# Passing an image from an img tag to the database or server folder(not choose file)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am using the image created from this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26Ws4/7/ and pass the image created from here to the database or a folder on the server(using paperclip).

In jsfiddle the img is initially created on the canvas and then to an img tag

```
<div class="canvas-wrap clearfix">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="700" width="700"></canvas>
</div>
```

Even if I use forms how to transfer the img to database/folder.

I am new to ruby on rails,the index page is the one in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have limited knowledge on this subject, but I believe you're dealing with an [HTML5 canvas object](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) -- which creates SVG-type graphics on the fly

---

**HTML5 Canvas != Image**

In order to transfer between the two, I would look to convert the HTML5 canvas render into an image object through Rails

I don't know anything about how to do this, but [this tutorial](http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/) does

---

**Paperclip**

To transfer into Paperclip, I would do this:

1. Transfer the Canvas render into an image (JS)
2. Send the image to Rails (Paperclip)
3. Use Paperclip to save the new record

I can write some code for this if you want, but it won't be tested or pretty

Comment: thnks for ur advice(the link) i tried some other way..but still wasnt successful.I tried using canvastodataurl but still i get an error undefined method for nil class. this is my new error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980880/sending-input-type-image-to-a-folder-on-the-server/21982678?noredirect=1#comment33314830_21982678

Comment: As u can see in the error page,i get the encoded image in the controller.but it isnt decoding..Do i need to add somethin in the model? also for base64 do i need to download some additional gem or something..as far i have read, i dont think so.